# Understanding cmp in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

I am looking at an assembly code that looks like the following:

```
cmp dword [rbp-0x4 {var_c}], 0x0
jne 0x12c0
```

To me, that reads:

> Compare the value of something and null, and if there is no error
>   (i.e. they match), jump to 0x12c0.

Is that correct? I don't understand what `[rbp-0x4 {var_c}]` is or why we would be comparing that to null.

I did try and follow a graph to learn what these variables were and I got the following:

- `0x4 = uint8_t file_class = 0x2`
- `var_c = In Set of Values {0, 1}`
- `rbp` seems to be what is pushed in from main

Any help on understanding this would be appreciated. I am looking for clarification on what is being compared in the `cmp` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, it's more:

> Compare the value of something with zero and, if they are not equal, jump.

Assembly language has no concept of "null" and a `cmp` is generally the same as a `sub` (subtract) but without actually changing the value. Basically, it's:

> Set the flags *as if* I had subtracted zero from something.

In more pseudo-code fashion, your two instructions amount to:

```
if var_c <> 0 then goto label_12c0
```

Answer (score 2):

> `rbp` seems to be what is pushed in from main

`rbp` is one CPU register that (like all CPU registers) stores a value.

I don't want to go too deep into detail here, but most compilers use the register `rbp` to store the information where the local variables (and sometimes function arguments) of the function are stored in the RAM memory:

The address (location in RAM memory) where a certain local variable is stored is typically calculated by subtracting some constant value from the value stored in the `rbp` register.

> I don't understand what `[rbp-0x4 {var_c}]` is ...

`dword [rbp-0x4]` means: A 32-bit value stored at the address `rbp-4`: The address which is calculated by subtracting the value 4 from the value stored in the register `rbp`.

The compiler has put additional information for a debugger into the binary file. This information says that the address of the local variable `var_c` is calculated by `rbp-4` and the address of the local variable `some_other_variable` is calculated by `rbp-10` and so on...

The disassembler has read this information and prints `{var_c}` after `rbp-0x4` to show that the variable `var_c` is located at the address `rbp-0x4`. So the 32-bit value "`dword [rbp-0x4]`" probably is the variable "`var_c`".

> 0x4 = uint8_t file_class = 0x2

I don't know which information this is. But the value `0x4` here has nothing to do with the value `0x4` in the disassembly line (`rbp-0x4`).

> ... and if there is no error (i.e. they match), jump to 0x12c0.

`jne` means: "**J**ump if **n**ot **e**qual".

This means that the CPU will jump if the variable `var_c` was **not** equal to 0.

Note that in compiled code representing an `if()` branch, the jump instruction will normally jump if the condition was *false*:

If the condition is *false*, the CPU jumps to the `else` part or to the first instruction after the `if()` part. If the condition is *true*, the CPU does **not** jump but execute the first instruction of the `if()` part which follows the `jne` (or similar) instruction.

Because your example jumps if `var_c` is *not* zero, it is probable that the source code was something like `if(var_c == 0)`.